# Mysql table scan

Tags: mysql

i have a table with about 1 million rows in a mysql 5 database. lately i learned that twitter does allow browsing only a certain number of tweets like last 600 or 6000. in my case user can browse to middle, end or begining of the records. from my point of view this functionality is not neessary, should i do what twitter did?

Answer (score 1):

I'd would dinamically set the limit by constantly checking the average load/cpu usage/query time of the database... That way when there are a few users online they can do their work faster. You could set a "maximum" like twitter and if total-load > max-load-you-want maximum=150% and so on...

On one of the service-based sites i've applied this method it actually removed 60% of the spikes after i told the users about the change...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system with <strike>20 million</strike> [190 million](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) active users then maybe.

Comment: downvoted with a false information. it is NOT 190m active users. it's 190m visitors per month! there is a big difference :)

Comment: If we're being pedantic, 190 million __unique__ visitors per month

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

**Beware of large LIMIT** ...

... for many web sites failing to take care of this provides very easy task to launch a DOS attack - request page with some large number from few connections and it is enough....